# How to integrate Rich with Python curses?

Tags: python, curses, python-curses, rich

I'm thinking of creating a CLI app using python `curses` and `rich` libraries. As `curses` requires `addstr` method to print text to string, I'm unable to print using `rich`. Is it possible to integrate these two libraries?

Following codes don't work accordingly!!

```py
import curses
from curses import wrapper
from rich.console import Console
console = Console()
with console.capture() as capture:
    console.print("[bold red]Hello[/] World")
str_output = capture.get()

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.addstr(str_output)
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()

wrapper(main)
```

Comment: You should avoid [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the built-in `print()` function in Python, in general

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Author of Rich here. Rich and Curses probably aren't going to work well in combination. However you could look in to [Textual](https://github.com/Textualize/textual) which is a TUI framework I'm working on that uses Rich under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to pipe the content from `rich` to `curses` but the `print()` function is not actually returning anything it is simply creating output on the terminal as a side effect of executing.

You can verify by looking at `type(print("[red]Hello[/red] World!"))` which is `<class 'NoneType'>`.

So, how can you retrieve the output from the `print(...)` ?  In the [docs for rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/console.html#capturing-output) they explain how this can be done with the Console API:

```
from rich.console import Console
console = Console()
with console.capture() as capture:
    console.print("[bold red]Hello[/] World")

str_output = capture.get()


>>> str_output
'\x1b[1;31mHello\x1b[0m World\n'
>>> print(str_output)
Hello World

>>> type(str_output)
<class 'str'>
```

Which allows you to access the output from the print and you can then try to pipe that information to curses.  You may run into some strange interferences from mixing `curses` and `rich` if you are overlapping their color contexts because of how color escape codes work in shells so be aware of that.

Comment: `curses` simply prints '\x1b[1;31mHello\x1b[0m World\n' as it is. 
curses requires followings to print colored codes 
```
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
stdscr.addstr(0, 0, str_output, curses.color_pair(1))
```

Comment: found this https://github.com/spellr/culour package .....but not compatible with colors used by rich